# JSTL - add parameters to call

Tags: java, jstl, el, jstl-functions

I have the following code in JSTL that retrieve student picture in j2ee site

```
 <c:if test="${student.studentPictureId != null}">
        <a href="javascript:showImage('<c:out value="${student.studentId}"/>','<c:out value="${student.studentPictureId }"/>
</c:if>
```

I would like to make the code more generic
instead of calling

```
 student.studentPictureId
```

I would like to call a generic function with an Enum :
function signature on the student class is like:

```
  Student class  
           String getPictureId(PictureTypeEnum picture type)
```

So final JSTL code will be like:

```
  <c:if test="${student.getPictureId(PictureTypeEnum.StudentCard) != null}">
        <a href="javascript:showImage('<c:out value="${student.studentId}"/>','<c:out value="${student.getPictureId(PictureTypeEnum.StudentCard)}"/>
</c:if>
```

I know that when calling

```
 <c:out value="${student.studentPictureId }"/>
```

Its basically calling a getter, student.getStudentPictureId()
student.studentPictureId

But Is it possible to invoke student object method and pass parameters to it?

Comment: EL 2.2 was introduced 2009 and supports this natively. Please move forward and catch up versions.

Comment: how to upgrade eclipse project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to directly call a method from JSTL, so I use a kind of a hack: a QuickMap:

```
public abstract class QuickMap<K,V> implements Map<K,V> {
    @Override
    public abstract V get(Object key);

    @Override
    public final int size() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

    @Override
    public final boolean isEmpty() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

    @Override
    public final boolean containsKey(Object key) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

    @Override
    public final boolean containsValue(Object value) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

    @Override
    public final V put(K key, V value) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

    @Override
    public final V remove(Object key) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

    @Override
    public final void putAll(Map<? extends K, ? extends V> m) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

    @Override
    public final void clear() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

    @Override
    public final Set<K> keySet() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

    @Override
    public final Collection<V> values() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

    @Override
    public final Set<Entry<K, V>> entrySet() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }
}
```

In your case, I would add the following method in your student class:

```
public Map<Object,String> getStudentPictureIds() {
    return new QuickMap<Object,String>() {
        @Override
        public String get(Object k) {
            PictureTypeEnum type;
            if (k instanceof PictureTypeEnum) {
                type = (PictureTypeEnum)k; 
            } else {
                type = PictureTypeEnum.valueOf(k.toString());
            }
            return getStudentPictureId(type);
        }            
    };
}
```

Not that it's not easy to manipulate enums with JSTL, so the method also accepts Strings.

You would use it as follows in your JSP:

```
<c:out value="${student.pictureIds['StudentCard']}"/>
```